# RecyclerView. Группировка данных

Tags: android, recyclerview

Есть список (RecyclerView), в котором идут временные промежутки. Не могу сообразить как можно сгруппировать эти промежутки по дням. Например.

---

День первый

10:00 - 10:20

13:14 - 15:10

---

День второй

10:00 - 10:20

13:14 - 15:10

---

День третий

10:00 - 10:20

13:14 - 15:10
....

Возможно, я что-то не доглядел. Заранее извиняюсь за глупый вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело здесь не в `RecyclerView`. `RecyclerView` лишь отображает прокручиваемый список объектов (если сильно упрощённо).

Вам нужно из тех данных, с которыми Вы работаете, сформировать объектную модель, которая связывает и описывает дни и связанные с ними события в определённом временном интервале.

Ниже представлен **общий набросок** подобной модели (для примера, думаю, будет достаточно полей классов).

```
// Событие
class Event{
    Date start;
    Date end;
    String description;
}
// День
class Day{
    Date date;
    String description;
    ArrayList<Event> events;
}
```

Сформировав список из дней Вы можете передать его в адаптер `RecyclerView`, в котором Вы сможете отобразить данные для каждого дня так, как Вам нужно.

Пример адаптера и макета не привожу, т.к. эта тема уже порядком избитая и легко ищется на SO и в гугле.